# Magic PartialFunction in Scala

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I don't think this code should work, but it does (in Scala 2.10):

```
scala>     ((i: Int) => i.toString match {
     |        case s if s.length == 2 => "A two digit number"
     |        case s if s.length == 3 => "A three digit number"
     |     }): PartialFunction[Int,String]
res0: PartialFunction[Int,String] = <function1>

// other interactions omitted

scala> res0.orElse(PartialFunction((i: Int) => i.toString))
res5: PartialFunction[Int,String] = <function1>

scala> res5(1)
res6: String = 1
```

How does it work? I would expect a `MatchError` to be thrown inside `res0`.

The Scala language specification does not seem to explicitly document how `res0` should be interpreted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that the compiler is not interpreting your definition as a total function converted to a partial function -- it's actually creating a partial function in the first place. You can verify by noting that `res0.isDefinedAt(1) == false`.

If you actually convert a total function to a partial function, you will get the behavior you expected:

```
scala> PartialFunction((i: Int) => i.toString match {
     |       case s if s.length == 2 => "A two digit number"
     |       case s if s.length == 3 => "A three digit number"
     |     })
res0: PartialFunction[Int,String] = <function1>

scala> res0 orElse ({ case i => i.toString }: PartialFunction[Int, String])
res1: PartialFunction[Int,String] = <function1>

scala> res1(1)
scala.MatchError: 1 (of class java.lang.String)
// ...
```

In this example, `PartialFunction.apply` treats its argument as a total function, so any information about where it's defined is lost.

Answer (score 2):

`orElse` is defined on `PartialFunction` so that the argument is treated as a fallback for the cases when the original is not defined. See [the API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.PartialFunction).

Comment: This doesn't explain why `res0` doesn't throw a `MatchError`.

Comment: It sort of does, really, if you read the documentation linked by @RobinGreen: `Composes this partial function with a fallback partial function which gets applied where this partial function is not defined.` `orElse` returns a new partial function which is defined for any value for which either `res0` or `res1` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You say that if `res0` does not match, you want to try your other pf instead. How this essentially works is:

```
if (res0.isDefinedAt(1)) {
  res0(1)
} else {
  other(1)
}
```

The orElse call creates an instance of `OrElse`, which inherits from `PartialFunction`: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala#L159

When you now call `apply` on this `OrElse`, it will call `f1.applyOrElse(x, f2)`: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala#L162

This will call `if (isDefinedAt(x)) apply(x) else f2(x)`: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala#L117-L118

Therefore you will only get a `MatchError`, when neither of the pf's matches.

Comment: I assumed that my attempt to produce a partial function from a total function in `res0` would result in an `isDefinedAt` that always returns `true`.

Comment: Exactly, but why do you expect a `MatchError` then?

Comment: Because it's actually a total function with a match inside it, masquerading as a partial function, or so I thought.

Comment: But if you have a `PartialFunction[Int, String]` it already says "I only accept Ints". If you now also don't have a guard, where should it not match?

Comment: If you would only call `res0`, then you would get a `MatchError`, but with the fallback to your total function, it will succeed. I don't understand why you would expect anything else.