# Why is this PartialFunction defined but still crashes (correctly) after application in Scala?

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I would like to try partial functions with a deep pattern matching use case. This initially (of course) didn't work after applying Some(Some(3)), but seemed defined instead :

```
def deepTest : PartialFunction [Option[Option[Int]], Int] = {
    case Some(v) => v match {
      case None => 3 
    }
    case None => 1
}
```

and I thought that by decoupling the nested pattern matching, things would be easier:

```
def deepTestLvl1 : PartialFunction [Option[Option[Int]], Option[Int]] = {
  case Some(v) => v
  case None => Some(1)
}


def deepTestLvl2 : PartialFunction [Option[Int], Int] = {
  case None => 3
}
```

but the result was the following:

```
scala> (deepTestLvl1 andThen deepTestLvl2) isDefinedAt(Some(Some(3)))
res24: Boolean = true
```

and after applying:

```
scala> (deepTestLvl1 andThen deepTestLvl2) (Some(Some(3)))
scala.MatchError: Some(3) (of class scala.Some)
    at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:248)
    at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:246)
    at $anonfun$deepTestLvl2$1.applyOrElse(<console>:7)
    at $anonfun$deepTestLvl2$1.applyOrElse(<console>:7)
        ....
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:83)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Am I doing something incorrectly? Shouldn't the isDefinedAt be called twice when I composed sequentially deepTestLvl{1,2} and give me the correct answer?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not documented properly in the Scala language specification - see [my anomalous partial function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973026/magic-partialfunction-in-scala), which works but is not really fully explained. Does anyone know of an actual reference which _does_ document the current behaviour of Scala partial functions correctly?

Comment: @RobinGreen Please check my answer. It's not documented, because it's not the way `andThen` is defined.

Comment: @krivachy.akos I was referring to `deepTest`.

Comment: Ah, in that case I think you would have to implement all combinations of the two partial functions. `case Some(None) => 3` and `case Some(Some(v)) => v`. It's not too elegant, especially considering the fact that the number of cases can grow exponentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good question.

Let's check the source and see what's happening under the covers:

```
override def andThen[C](k: B => C): PartialFunction[A, C] =
  new AndThen[A, B, C] (this, k)
```

We can observe here that `andThen` **doesn't even expect a Partial Function**, any Function that transforms the result will do. Your code works, because: `trait PartialFunction[-A, +B] extends (A => B)`. This can actually be found in [the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction):

> `def andThen[C](k: (B) ⇒ C): PartialFunction[A, C]`
>
> Composes this partial function with a transformation function that gets applied to results of this partial function.
>
> **C** the result type of the transformation function.
>
> **k** the transformation function
>
> **returns** a partial function with the same domain as this partial function, which maps arguments `x` to `k(this(x))`.

So there's currently no way to chain `PartialFunction`s in the way you would like, because as Robin said, it would require applying the function. Next to being computationally expensive **it could also have side effects**, which is a bigger problem.

### Update

Whipped together an implementation you're looking for. **Use it cautiously!** As I already mentioned, if your code has side effects it will cause problems:

```
implicit class PartialFunctionExtension[-A, B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]) {
  def andThenPf[C](pf2: PartialFunction[B, C]) = new PfAndThen(pf, pf2)

  class PfAndThen[+C](pf: PartialFunction[A, B], nextPf: PartialFunction[B, C]) extends PartialFunction[A, C] {
    def isDefinedAt(x: A) = pf.isDefinedAt(x) && nextPf.isDefinedAt(pf.apply(x))

    def apply(x: A): C = nextPf(pf(x))
  }
}
```

Trying it out:

```
deepTestLvl1.andThenPf(deepTestLvl2).isDefinedAt(Some(Some(3)))  // false
deepTestLvl1.andThenPf(deepTestLvl2).isDefinedAt(Some(None))     // true
deepTestLvl1.andThenPf(deepTestLvl2).apply(Some(None))           // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `isDefinedAt` on a `PartialFunction` produced by `andThen` returns inconsistent results is that *it doesn't actually apply the first partial function to its argument*, which could be an expensive operation.

This behaviour is likely to trip people up and isn't documented - you might want to submit a patch to add documentation for that.

P.S. My guess is that the reason for `deepTest` to behave as it does, is that the outermost `match` in the source code of a partial function definition, and *only* the outermost match, is considered for definedness purposes - but you'd have to check the source code of `scalac` to be sure, I think.

Comment: On Coursera "Principles of Reactive Programming" Martin Odersky explains that indeed only the outermost match is considered.